# Spring Integration - Apache ActiveMQ to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-transactions

I am using the below configuration for integrating activemq with kafka. I receive message from activemq and forwards it to kafka. However, i am noticing that messages are getting dequeued from JMS Queue but messages are not going to kafka.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd">

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="helloJMSAdapater" destination="helloJMSQueue" connection-factory="jmsConnectionfactory"
        channel="helloChannel" extract-payload="true" />

    <integration:channel id="helloChannel" />

    <integration:service-activator id="sayHelloServiceActivator"
        input-channel="helloChannel" ref="sayHelloService" method="sayHello" />

    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-template="template"
        auto-startup="false" sync="true" channel="helloChannel" topic="test1234" 
        >
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                        <!--entry key="retries" value="5" /> <entry key="batch.size" value="16384" 
                            /> <entry key="linger.ms" value="1" /> <entry key="buffer.memory" value="33554432" 
                            /> < entry key="key.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" 
                            /> <entry key="value.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" 
                            / -->
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Also, in case there is any issue from Kafka, it is not even reporting any exception stack trace.

Did i miss anything ?

Comment: I don't know Spring so well but in Kafka you need to configure acks=all to get acks when the brokers store your message. If acks=0 you will get no acknowledgement of success or failure to commit the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your messages are consumed by sayHelloServiceActivator.

So change your helloChannel channel type to

```
<publish-subscribe-channel id="helloChannel"/>
```

Default is DirectChannel

> The DirectChannel has point-to-point semantics but otherwise is more
>   similar to the PublishSubscribeChannel than any of the queue-based
>   channel implementations described above. It implements the
>   SubscribableChannel interface instead of the PollableChannel
>   interface, so it dispatches Messages directly to a subscriber. As a
>   point-to-point channel, however, it differs from the
>   PublishSubscribeChannel in that it will only send each Message to a
>   single subscribed MessageHandler.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I noticed that my serviceActivator was void type and hence, it was not going forward.  I am able to send messages now from jms to kafka. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hassen Bennour says, if you want to send a message to two consumers, you need a publish/subscribe channel.

That said, you have `auto-startup="false"` on the kafka adapter, so it won't even be subscribed to the channel.

If it was started, with your current configuration messages would be sent round-robin alternately to the service activator and adapter.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I noticed that my serviceActivator was void type and hence, it was not going forward.  I am able to send messages now from jms to kafka. Thanks for your inputs.